# Как сделать эффект быстрой смены картинок за определенное время

Tags: javascript, css, анимация

Есть несколько блоков. Как при наведении сделать быстрое изменение картинок как в начальных титрах фильмах Marvel?

То есть к примеру за 5 секунд быстро, как внизу изменились картинки. В конце после 3 или 4-ой секунды уже менялись не так быстро, то есть желательно, так же как в приведенном примере только без текста.

**Что нибудь такое только при наведении:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пока у меня ничего не получилось толком.

```css
.image {
  width:300px;
  height:150px;
  border:1px solid lightblue;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.image img:hover {
webkit-transform: scale(1.20,1.20);
-moz-transform: scale(1.20,1.20);
transform: scale(1.20,1.20);
  transition: all .2s;
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <img src="http://d2lzb5v10mb0lj.cloudfront.net/covers_tfaw/400/ju/jun190856.jpg">
  <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3794/10.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3794/9.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3794/8.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3794/7.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3794/6.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3794/5.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3794/4.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3794/3.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3794/2.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3794/1.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
arr = [
  "http://d2lzb5v10mb0lj.cloudfront.net/covers_tfaw/400/ju/jun190856.jpg",
  "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3794/10.jpg",
  "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3794/9.jpg",
  "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3794/8.jpg",
  "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3794/7.jpg",
  "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3794/6.jpg",
  "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3794/5.jpg",
  "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3794/4.jpg",
  "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3794/3.jpg",
  "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3794/2.jpg",
  "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3794/1.jpg",
];

let interval = null;
let iteartor = 0;

display();

$("#img").on("mouseenter", function() {
  var interval = setInterval(() => {
    display();
  }, 50);
})


function display() {
  $("#img").attr("src", arr[iteartor]);
  iteartor++;
  if (iteartor > arr.length) clearInterval(interval);
}
```

```css
.images {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid lightblue;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image img:hover {
  webkit-transform: scale(1.20, 1.20);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.20, 1.20);
  transform: scale(1.20, 1.20);
  transition: all .2s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="images">
  <img id="img" height="100%" width="100%" />

</div>
```

Comment: Неплохо O.o (+1).Сделайте чтобы при наведении работало анимация и я приму ответ.Спасибо.

Comment: @Demon__ сделал..сразу не заметил )

Comment: Спасибо принцип работы понял.

Comment: + Можно куда-нибудь заранее выгрузить все картинки, чтобы не начинали вдруг загружаться в момент наведения)

Answer (score 5):

Кадров конечно надо побольше) И желательно перескринить их соразмерно с блоком-родителем, чтобы быстрее загружались.

```js
let image = document.querySelector('.image');
let frame = image.querySelectorAll('img');
let timeout = null;

image.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
  let time = 5; // Время перелистывания
  let i = 0;

  change();

  function change() {
    time += 5;
    frame[i].style.zIndex = 100;
    if (frame[++i]) {
      // Если существует следующая картинка - функция вызывает сама себя.
      timeout = setTimeout(change, time); // Уже с увеличенным временем.
    }
  }
});

image.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  for( let i = 0; i < frame.length; i++ ){
    frame[i].style.zIndex = 0;
  }
});
```

```css
.image {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid lightblue;
}

.image img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <img src="http://d2lzb5v10mb0lj.cloudfront.net/covers_tfaw/400/ju/jun190856.jpg">
  <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3794/10.jpg">
  <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3794/9.jpg">
  <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3794/8.jpg">
  <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3794/7.jpg">
  <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3794/6.jpg">
  <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3794/5.jpg">
  <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3794/4.jpg">
  <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3794/3.jpg">
  <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3794/2.jpg">
  <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3794/1.jpg">
  
  <img src="http://d2lzb5v10mb0lj.cloudfront.net/covers_tfaw/400/ju/jun190856.jpg">
  <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3794/10.jpg">
  <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3794/9.jpg">
  <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3794/8.jpg">
  <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3794/7.jpg">
  <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3794/6.jpg">
  <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3794/5.jpg">
  <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3794/4.jpg">
  <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3794/3.jpg">
  <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3794/2.jpg">
  <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3794/1.jpg">
  
  <img src="http://d2lzb5v10mb0lj.cloudfront.net/covers_tfaw/400/ju/jun190856.jpg">
  <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3794/10.jpg">
  <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3794/9.jpg">
  <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3794/8.jpg">
  <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3794/7.jpg">
  <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3794/6.jpg">
  <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3794/5.jpg">
  <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3794/4.jpg">
  <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3794/3.jpg">
  <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3794/2.jpg">
  <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3794/1.jpg">
  
  <img src="http://d2lzb5v10mb0lj.cloudfront.net/covers_tfaw/400/ju/jun190856.jpg">
  <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3794/10.jpg">
  <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3794/9.jpg">
  <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3794/8.jpg">
  <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3794/7.jpg">
  <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3794/6.jpg">
  <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3794/5.jpg">
  <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3794/4.jpg">
  <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3794/3.jpg">
  <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3794/2.jpg">  
  <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3794/1.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: Идеально).Благодарю но к сожалению я уже принял ответ. +1

Comment: Но я не понял какой код замедляет их в конце?

Comment: @Demon__ `time += 5;` — при каждом вызове функции, время следующего вызова увеличивается на 5 миллисекунд)

Comment: Про увеличение я понял ,но как замедляется ?)

Comment: @Demon__ Кажется путаете setTimeout и setInterval) В этом примере запускается setTimeout через `time` миллисекунд, который срабатывает ровно один раз. А вызываемая при этом функция `change` только после своего срабатывания - снова запускает другой `setTimeout`, который ждет дольше (т.к. time увеличен), чем предыдущий вызов. В итоге вызовы происходят на 0-й миллисекунде, потом 10-й, 25-й, 45-й, 70-й, 100-й, 135-й...

Comment: Аааа теперь понял )).Спасибо еще раз.Вопросов нету больше.